# Why onchange event taking me to new page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to populate a text field with the value of the select field.
So based on the selection the text field should change.
In this case, I am selecting First Name and Last name of the person and in the

```
option value="I have person email here"
```

Now, I am using `onchange` event on select element which calls the `findemail()` function.
Problem is I am getting the correct emails return but
**it redirect me to another page and show me the value there.**

Can anyone please help me?

CODE

```
    function findemail(e)
{
    document.getElementById('man-email-add').innerHTML=document.write(e.value);
}
```

HTML (I am using PHP to get all the values)

```
<select id="manager_detail" onchange="findemail(this.options[this.selectedIndex]);">            


<?php 

    foreach ($data['display']['userMangers'] as $manager){
      echo   $manEmail = $manager['Email'];
      echo "<option value='$manEmail'>".$manager['First_Name'].' '.$manager['Last_Name'].'  ('.$manager['Position'].')'.'</option>';
}
    
?>


                              </select>
```

Redirect to new page to show the value:

[image]

Comment: Where did you learn to do `.innerHTML=document.write(e.value);`

Comment: isn't document.write like echo in php? like print screen stuff. Sorry I am new to JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're using `document.write()` after the page has loaded, which doesn't look necessary here anyway:

```
document.getElementById('man-email-add').innerHTML= e.value;
```

Comment: If I use this document.getElementById('man-email-add').innerHTML= e.value; it's not populating the field either, man-email-add field.

Comment: Are you sure you have an element with the id `man-email-add`? Have you debugged the value of `e.value`?

Comment: For some reason it's not letting me to populate that field. It's saying webform is disabled something. So can you please tell me then how can I assign the value to the value field of the input man-email-add? Yes i debugged and the values are showing in console but in on the page input box.

Comment: `man-email-add` is an input? Then you would assign its `value`, not its `innerHTML`: `document.getElementById('man-email-add').value = e.value;`

Comment: Great! Thanks heaps. Just to learn then in what cases I can use innerHTML?

Comment: Well, when you want to change an element's html. `input` elements can't have descendants, so you aren't allowed to change their html. `div`s, `p`s, `a`s (for example), on the other hand, can all have html within them.

Answer (score 0):

Does it redirect to new page or reloads the same page showing the email? I believe it's doing the later as `document.write(e.value);` writes that value to the page. So replace `document.write(e.value);` with `e.value;`

If `man-email-add` is an input field, use `document.getElementById('man-email-add').value=e.value;`

Comment: Reloads in the same page

Comment: @Jason P walk me through. Thank you for looking into it.